# Mac 10.4 osascript unicode issue

Tags: macos, applescript

osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "Æ"'

This works on 10.5 and 10.6 but doesn't work on 10.4. From what I understand osascript on Mac 10.4 defaults to MacRoman encoding. So on 10.4 this becomes garbled letters. Is there a work around for this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's been ages since I've had a 10.4 Mac at my desk, but what about something like `tell application "System Events" to keystroke ("Æ" as Unicode text)`.